# Directional/nondirectional graph library for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm in the process of developing yet another social network. No, we don't need another one - I'm just doing it to get a better understanding of big social systems and databases. I want to use Python Google App Engine and I prefer the datastore/nosql to the CloudSQL. When it comes to storing users I'm looking to storing them as a undirected graph, to leverage from the understanding and algorithms of such a structure. I could implement this easily with a list of edges/friendships within each node/user, but what I really want is to use a library like NetworkX and leverage from what they've been building. I could just get started with nx, but as the graph expands it won't fit in memcache and need some sort of persistent storage. It won't help to save the graph as graphML and just rebuild the graph as it will still take the same amount of memory.

So I need a system which supports an infinitely large graph, with only parts of it in memcache for app engine. Does it exist?